# Force usage of 10.x wheel in MacOS Big Sur

Tags: python, macos, pip

I've recently upgraded my MacOS to Big Sur. When I try to install Python packages using pip no wheel is found and everything is forced to be built from source resulting in very slow installation and, worst, many installation errors because of limitations of the build environment. Check for instance https://pypi.org/simple/numpy/. Given that I'm using Python 3.8, the closest available wheel is `numpy-1.19.4-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl`. I would like to force pip using these wheels for `macosx_10_9` and see what happens. Do you know of any way to achieve that?

Comment: Sorry I'm failing to see how the comment addresses my concern, this is not related to environments but to platforms and wheel usage.

Comment: Regarding the C API incompatibility, the current build is for Maverics and even if Big Sur have changed the major version I believe it's mostly because of the face lift and commercial reasons. My interest is to "see what happens" as I said in the question.

Answer (score 4):

I'm answering to myself with a workaround to force the platform, for example for numpy:

```
pip install --platform macosx_10_9_x86_64 --only-binary=:all: --target=/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages numpy
```

Sadly the `--target` option is necessary although there are plans to remove this requirement (https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5453).

I've requested that `pip` takes macosx_10_9 as valid for Big Sur in https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9138, but I guess the probability that this proposal will be rejected is high.

I don't know how long it takes for new wheels to be built for a new platform, but I assume the workaround is good enough in the meantime.

---

A second, dirtier but more convenient hack is to override `version_str`:

```
    version_str, _, cpu_arch = platform.mac_ver()  # type: ignore
    version_str = "10.15.1"
```

in `site-packages/pip/_vendor/packaging/tags.py`

Comment: Is there a reason for using `10_9` specifically?

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been losing my mind and your pip hack has fixed this. I hope that the ecosystem can update wheels quickly so no one else has to go through this.